# How to reference the type of a private class from an assembly-level attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, class-attributes

I have defined an assembly level attribute class `FooAttribute` like this:

```
namespace Bar
{
    [System.AttributeUsage (System.AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple=true)]
    public sealed class FooAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public FooAttribute(string id, System.Type type)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

and I use it to associate an *id* to classes, for instance:

```
[assembly: Bar.Foo ("MyClass", typeof (Bar.MyClass))]

namespace Bar
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private class Mystery { }
    }
}
```

This all works fine. But what if I need to somehow reference the private class `Mystery`, defined in `MyClass`? Is this at all possible? Trying to reference it from the top-level `[assembly: ...]` directive does not work, as the type is not publicly visible:

```
[assembly: Bar.Foo ("Mystery", typeof (Bar.MyClass.Mystery))] // won't work
```

And trying to put the `[assembly: ...]` directive into `MyClass` in so that it could see `Mystery` is not legal, as `[assembly: ...]` must be defined at the top level:

```
namespace Bar
{
    class MyClass
    {
        [assembly: FooAttribute (...)] // won't work either
        ...
    }
}
```

There is a way to access `internal` types from outside of an assembly by declaring the user a *friend* of the assembly, but how about referencing private types inside an assembly? I guess it is not possible, and I just would have to declare `Mystery` to be `internal` instead, but I want to be sure I did not miss some subtlety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertions in your last paragraphs are correct. Your options would be to:

- Make the nested class internal to enable `typeof`

or

- Have an added constructor to `FooAttribute` which takes the fully qualified type name of the private nested class, and then uses reflection to get a `System.Type` representing it.

For instance:

```
public sealed class FooAttribute
{
    public FooAttribute(string id, string typeName)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        // whatever the other ctor does with the System.Type...
    }
}
```

usage:

```
[assembly: Foo("Bar", typeof(Bar))]
[assembly: Foo("Baz", "Foo.Bar+Baz, MyAssembly")]

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        private class Baz
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be `Bar+Baz`, not `Bar.Baz`, surely?

Comment: Well spotted Marc! Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Making it `internal` (which you already state you don't want to do) is the least effort approach. For the majority of code, allowing `MyClass` to expose (via a static property) the *type* instance (i.e. `public static Type MysteryType { get { return typeof(Mystery); } }` would work, but that *won't* work from an attribute (only constant values of a few basic types can be used).

The only alternative to `internal`, then, is to code it as a *string literal*, (i.e. `[Foo("Bar.MyClass+Mystery")]`) and use `typeof(MyClass).Assembly.GetType(fullName)` - but then you lose the compiler validation that `typeof` normally provides. (note also the `+` that the runtime uses to represent nested types, not `.` which is the C# representation)

Personally, I'd just make it `internal`.